# How to perform an Insertion Sort algorithm on an array of objects based on a String parameter?

Tags: java, sorting

I have two classes: Movie2 and TestMovie2.

Movie2 is as follows:

```
public class Movie2 
{
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private String studio;

    Movie2(String title, int year, String studio)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.studio = studio;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getStudio()
    {
        return studio;
    }

    public void setStudio(String studio)
    {
        this.studio = studio;
    }
}
```

TestMovie2 is as follows:

```
public class TestMovie2 
{
    private static Movie2[] myMovies = new Movie2[10];

    private static void addMovies()
    {
        myMovies[0] = new Movie2("The Muppets Take Manhattan", 2001, "Columbia Tristar");
        myMovies[1] = new Movie2("Mulan Special Edition", 2004, "Disney");
        myMovies[2] = new Movie2("Shrek 2", 2004, "Dreamworks");
        myMovies[3] = new Movie2("The Incredibles", 2004, "Pixar");
        myMovies[4] = new Movie2("Nanny McPhee", 2006, "Universal");
        myMovies[5] = new Movie2("The Curse of the Were-Rabbit", 2006, "Aardman");
        myMovies[6] = new Movie2("Ice Age", 2002, "20th Century Fox");
        myMovies[7] = new Movie2("Lilo & Stitch", 2002, "Disney");
        myMovies[8] = new Movie2("Robots", 2005, "20th Century Fox");
        myMovies[9] = new Movie2("Monsters", 2001, "Pixar");
    }

    private static void printMovies()
    {
        for (Movie2 i : myMovies)
        {
            System.out.printf("\n%-30s%10s%30s", i.getTitle(), i.getYear(), i.getStudio());
        }
    }

    private static void sortTitles()
    {

        for (Movie2 i : myMovies)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        addMovies();
        printMovies();
        sortTitles();
    }   
}
```

Within sortTitles(), I'm trying to create an algorithm that will sort the objects (the movies) in a based on their titles. Unfortunately I can't use Arrays.sort(), or anything similar. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me an example of a String sorter, then explain how it works line-by-line so I can implement one in my project.

Edit: I can't use Arrays.sort() because it is against the instructions of the assignment.

Comment: Why can't you use Arrays.sort()? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator- I can see no reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: Try `Arrays.sort(myMovies, Comparator.comparing(Movie2::getTitle));`

Comment: @michael-lilley, I have provided a sort implementation. Hope that helps!

Comment: @MSameer I actually figured out the algorithm as soon as you posted; thank you for your help though!

Comment: @MichaelLilley, Glad I could help. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the purpose of doing this project is to learn the sorting algorithm. I don't thinks it's a good idea to give you the code, which you won't learn much from it. Here is an easy sorting algorithm called insertion sort, example: http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/insertion-sort/. You can use String.compareTo(anotherString) to sort your titles.

In addition, there are many other nice sorting algorithm you can use to improve performance, such as merge sort and quick sort. I can help you walk through the algorithm, but not giving you the code. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Option1: Using Arrays.sort()
Like others have suggested, you should be able to use Arrays.sort().

Now, Arrays.sort() on a primitive type like say int[] automatically sorts it in ascending order Example: int[] numbers, then Arrays.sort(numbers).

In you case since you want to sort non-primitive type array of movies.
You will need to write a comparator class and pass it into Arrays.sort(movies, [Your MoviesComparator Instance]). 
Look at example 3 in this link [Sorting](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-arrays-examples-with-comparable-and-comparator) 
, it creates a comparator to sort on salary, you want to create a similar comparator and sort on title. Hope this helps.

Option2: Writing your own sort method.
I have provided a sample using selection sort.

```
public class Solution {

/**
 * Movie pojo
 */
public static class Movie {
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private String studio;

    Movie(String title, int year, String studio) {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.studio = studio;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getStudio() {
        return studio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Title" +  this.getTitle() + " : " + "Year" +  this.getYear() + " : " + "Studio" + this.getStudio();
    }
}

/**
 * Sort movies on titles using selection sort
 * @param movies
 */
public static void sortMovieTitles(Movie[] movies) {
     /*Algorithm: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)
    Idea is to iterate & find the min element in every iteration and place it lowest index position */
    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length - 1; ++i)
    {
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < movies.length; ++j)
        {
            if (movies[j].title.compareTo(movies[minIndex].title) < 0)
            {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        Movie tempMovie = movies[i];
        movies[i] = movies[minIndex];
        movies[minIndex] = tempMovie;
    }

    //print
   for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(movies[i]);
   }
}


/**
 * Main
 * @param args input args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    Movie[] myMovies = new Movie[10];
    myMovies[0] = new Movie("The Muppets Take Manhattan", 2001, "Columbia Tristar");
    myMovies[1] = new Movie("Mulan Special Edition", 2004, "Disney");
    myMovies[2] = new Movie("Shrek 2", 2004, "Dreamworks");
    myMovies[3] = new Movie("The Incredibles", 2004, "Pixar");
    myMovies[4] = new Movie("Nanny McPhee", 2006, "Universal");
    myMovies[5] = new Movie("The Curse of the Were-Rabbit", 2006, "Aardman");
    myMovies[6] = new Movie("Ice Age", 2002, "20th Century Fox");
    myMovies[7] = new Movie("Lilo & Stitch", 2002, "Disney");
    myMovies[8] = new Movie("Robots", 2005, "20th Century Fox");
    myMovies[9] = new Movie("Monsters", 2001, "Pixar");
    sortMovieTitles(myMovies);

}
```

}

```
 //Output:
  TitleIce Age : Year2002 : Studio20th Century Fox
  TitleLilo & Stitch : Year2002 : StudioDisney
  TitleMonsters : Year2001 : StudioPixar
  TitleMulan Special Edition : Year2004 : StudioDisney
  TitleNanny McPhee : Year2006 : StudioUniversal
  TitleRobots : Year2005 : Studio20th Century Fox
  TitleShrek 2 : Year2004 : StudioDreamworks
  TitleThe Curse of the Were-Rabbit : Year2006 : StudioAardman
  TitleThe Incredibles : Year2004 : StudioPixar
  TitleThe Muppets Take Manhattan : Year2001 : StudioColumbia Tristar
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, code is below:

```
private static void sortTitles(Movie2[] input)
{   
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        Movie2 temp;

        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (input[j].getTitle().compareTo(input[j-1].getTitle()) < 0)
            {
                temp = input[j];
                input[j] = input[j - 1];
                input[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (Movie2 i : input)
    {
        System.out.printf("\n%-30s%10s%30s", i.getTitle(), i.getYear(), i.getStudio());
    }
}
```

This algorithm changes this:

```
The Muppets Take Manhattan          2001              Columbia Tristar
Mulan Special Edition               2004                        Disney
Shrek 2                             2004                    Dreamworks
The Incredibles                     2004                         Pixar
Nanny McPhee                        2006                     Universal
The Curse of the Were-Rabbit        2006                       Aardman
Ice Age                             2002              20th Century Fox
Lilo & Stitch                       2002                        Disney
Robots                              2005              20th Century Fox
Monsters                            2001                         Pixar
```

to this:

```
Ice Age                             2002              20th Century Fox
Lilo & Stitch                       2002                        Disney
Monsters                            2001                         Pixar
Mulan Special Edition               2004                        Disney
Nanny McPhee                        2006                     Universal
Robots                              2005              20th Century Fox
Shrek 2                             2004                    Dreamworks
The Curse of the Were-Rabbit        2006                       Aardman
The Incredibles                     2004                         Pixar
The Muppets Take Manhattan          2001              Columbia Tristar
```

Thanks for your help everyone!